# Find serial number of previously connected macbook charger

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, charging, charger

I lost my (MacBook Pro Thunderbolt-3/USB-C) charger in my school, and I want to believe that someone took it mistakenly, not that someone stole it.

To increase the likelihood of finding the charger, I want to provide the serial number of my charger so that others can check themselves to see if they took away my charger by mistake. However, since I already lost it, I can't find it from `System Information`.

Is this information stored/cached somewhere on the disk? How can I find it? (I have backups of the system before the charger was lost).

Screenshot to explain what I'm looking for: `Serial Number`.

[image]

Comment: Schools are notorious for things just "wandering off". When I was about 6, I went home in someone else's coat… & they in mine. This was all quickly resolved because **everything had a name tag**. ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I did wrote my name on it using permanent markers 3 years ago, but I guess it eventually wears off and I did not add my name again. I now have a solution which is to cover the marks with (clear plastic) tape.